# Delete a folder that does not match a pattern

Tags: command-line, wildcards

I have two folders, one that I know the name of, and one that I don't:

```bsh
~/foobar-as9df7 # I know the name of this one
~/foobar-7fq92h # I don't know the name of that one
```

How can I delete the folder that starts with `foobar-` and is NOT `~/foobar-as9df7`, and that I don't know the name of?

Said differently, I want to `rm -rf ~/foobar-as9df7` except that I don't know it's called `foobar-as9df7`, I only know its name starts with `foobar-` and it's not `foobar-as9df7`.

I've tried doing:

```bsh
find foobar-* ! -name "foobar-as9df7"  -exec rm -rf {} \;
```

which works but strangely this triggers a message saying:

```
find: ‘foobar-7fq92h’: No such file or directory
```

**-- EDIT**

the output of this command:

```bsh
find ~/ -type d -name 'foobar-*' ! -name 'foobar-as9df7' -exec echo .rm -r {} +
```

is as follows:

```
.rm -r /home/ubuntu/foobar-7fq92h
```

Comment: What shell are you using?

Comment: using bash shell

Comment: Perfect, the answers in the dupe should be exactly what you need then. Something like `shopt -s extglob; rm -r ~/foobar-!(as9df7)`.

Comment: is there an equivalent to `shopt -s extglob` for `zsh`, ideally that would work with both of them?

Comment: Yes, but I don't know what it is. Zsh can do far fancier stuff than that so I am sure it can do it, but if you need a zsh-specific way, then please edit your question to clarify. Also, the `find` approach given in the answers of the dupe should work for any shell. If that isn't enough and you still want a zsh-only solution, edit your question so it can be reopened.

Comment: looks like zsh and bash have completely different syntax and extensions

Comment: I find it crazy that this question was marked as "duplicate" so quickly — I'm still struggling to adapt the answers from the other question — if that was a real duplicate I wouldn't be struggling

Comment: OK, that's why I left the comment here so you could easily ping me and let me know if the dupe was not right. But please edit and explain _why_ the answers don't work for you. Simply saying it isn't a dupe when it certainly looks like one doesn't help us understand how to help you.

Comment: The commands in your case would be `shopt -s extglob; rm -r ~/foobar-!(as9df7)` in bash. Or, with `find` it would be `find ~/ -type d -name 'foobar-*' ! -name 'foobar-as9df7' -exec rm -r {} +` doesn't work. Since the main issue is the same, we prefer not to cover it again. If the problem was reaching the commands I just gave (which is understandable if you're not familiar with the syntax of the relevant tools), it is probably not worth having a separate question since the main answers are given in the dupe.

Comment: alright — I've tried to use the `find` command but somehow it says that `find: ‘foobar-1e91d’: No such file or directory` despite successfully removing it, which is weird

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/121182/discussion-between-terdon-and-jivan).